# How to set validation correctly by regex in typeorm and nest.js

Tags: regex, typescript, typeorm, class-validator

I'd like to set `boolean` validation, it means it only permit `0 or 1`.

`entity.ts`

```
  @Column('int')
  isLastdate: number;
```

I set above rule by following `regular expression`

`dto.ts`

```
const boolRegex = /^[01]$/


  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsInt()
  @Matches(boolRegex,{
    message:`isLastdate must be bool (0 or 1)`
  })
  isLastdate: number;
```

I throw following `json` to the api-server

```
{
"userId":1,
"title":"mytest",
"date":"2000-12-31",
"isLastdate":1,
"beginTime":"11:59",
"endTime":"23:40",
"place":"Tokyo",
"labelCd":1
}
```

But the response is following.
Are there anything wrong with my validation ?

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "isLastdate must be bool (0 or 1)"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: not sure you need to pass `@Column('int') ` . try `@Column() ` instead

Comment: I changed `@Column()` but it still have errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of type int, try going for boolean, both in your dto and entity
`@Column('boolean')`.
If you really need 0 or 1 in request, map them to boolean while saving in the database.

Answer (score 0):

use @IsNumberString instead @IsInt